# Does React Native android APK Expansion support?

Tags: android, react-native

I tried to search "React Native Android APK Expansion" and couldn't find any page about it. Does RN support APK Expansion file? How can I test it in local dev?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't directly.

Comment: Found this https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video/pull/142/files

Comment: Any solution yet?

Comment: any luck figuring it out?