# How can i use APK Expansion Files with React-Native

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files, react-native

I'm building an application with the use of many sound files with big sizes. So problem is that my APK file is much bigger than the 100Mb limit, and I need to use APK Expansion Files. I tried searching on the internet how to handle this but found nothing.
Maybe some of you already faced this problem and know how to fix it.

Thanks.

Comment: any luck with this?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36039134/does-react-native-android-apk-expansion-support

Comment: any luck figuring it out?

Comment: @Ron that was 2 years ago, but as i remember i wrote react-extension to use google APK extension API. The only problem was that that API had a bug and path of APK extension file on device was calculated wrong. i think they had bad copy past there.